# Is it possible to use Eclipse null analysis in combination with Lombok?

Tags: java, eclipse, nullable, lombok, type-annotation

We are using [Eclipse null analysis](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_null_annotations.htm) heavily in our Java code base. Recently, more teams started to use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/).

I struggle to get both working together. For instance, when using the [`@Builder`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder.html) annotation, its generated functions lack the `@Nullable` annotation. Also the concept of [`NonNullByDefault`](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/annotation/NonNullByDefault.html) (from Eclipse) is problematic in Lombok.

**I wonder if is it possible to use Eclipse null analysis in combination with Lombok?** At the moment, I am under the impression that it is not possible, but I hope that I am missing something.

Since upgrading to Java 8, we switched to [@Nullable type annotations](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_null_type_annotations.htm), which is also a problem for the Lombok alternative [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value). If Lombok supports the old Java 7 style annotations but not a [JSR 308](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-architect-annotations-2177655.html) based `@Nullable` annotation, unfortunately, it would not be useful in our code base.

Side-note: Although the question is Eclipse specific, as it refers to the null analysis of Eclipse, personally I mostly work with IDEA. So, if it is possible to get IntelliJ's null analysis working with Lombok, it would be interesting, too.

Comment: In what way is @Nullable a problem for AutoValue?

Comment: @LouisWasserman AutoValue has good support for Nullable annotations that are available using the Java 7 reflection API. Unfortunately, type annotations can only be accessed with Java 8, so supporting them would break Java 7 compatibility. One of my collegues experimentally patched AutoValue to use the Java 8 API and it seems to work. However, to get a patch integrated, I guess you have to write it in a backwards compatible way (which is possible using reflection). I don't think Google is willing to break the Java 7 compatibility.

Comment: Is there an issue filed about that on GitHub?  (I am on the team that maintains AutoValue.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Not that I'm aware of, but I can create one as a feature request.

Comment: @LouisWasserman https://github.com/google/auto/issues/283